# Lumen Apple Sign in

Tags: php, laravel, lumen, laravel-socialite

I want to use apple sign-in feature in my Rest API. To implement this feature I follow all steps from https://socialiteproviders.netlify.app/providers/apple.html. But getting error `Driver [apple] not supported`.

I am using

- Lumen version 5.7
- socialite version: 4.1
- socialiteproviders/apple version : 3.0

I tried with Lumen new version(7.0), but still getting same error.

Comment: stop laravel serve and clear config then restart serve

Comment: @MortadaJafar I tried you suggestion but still not working.

Comment: As socialiteproviders/apple package dependency on laravel/socialite, my code can't find AppleProvider.php provider file in vendor/laravel/socialite (like: GoogleProvider.php, FacebookProvider.php, etc..)